# How to Have 2 variables using FOR work simultaneously in batch command?

Tags: batch-file, mkv

I am using mkvmerge to extract audio from multiple files. When doing that, I want to rename the extracted files so it is easier for me to merge them later.

My command right now is this

```
for /f "delims=" %%A IN ('dir /b *.mkv') DO mkvextract tracks "%%A" 2:F:\%%~nA.ogg
```

Which extracts an audio from a file say "x1.mkv" to "x1.ogg"

What I want to do is, rename the audio file (x1.ogg) to the name of another file from another folder. 
Kinda like this command (Which I know is wrong, I'm trying to tell what I want to achieve):

```
for /f "delims=" %%A IN ('dir /b *.mkv') && %%B in ('dir "F:\Show" /b *.mkv') DO mkvextract tracks "%%A" 2:F:\%%~nB.ogg
```

Which Takes a file from my current directory (%%A) , but the extracted audio will have the name of the corresponding file in another directory (%%B).

Thus,

x1.mkv => y1.ogg

x2.mkv => y2.ogg and so on..

So how do I type the FOR command in which 2 variables have names of files of 2 different directories?

Thanks!

Comment: Is the name format always x and y followed by a number? Is the number of files in those folder the same?

Comment: No not exactly the same format.. The names are different  but the number of files are exactly the same.

Comment: How do you know how to pair the different names? Doesn't matter (random)? Sorted alphabetically? Sorted by date? Common element in each name?

Comment: Alphabetically. I'm not sure if i'm allowed to do this. Here's a [screenshot](http://imgur.com/qjKzC1s) I want to extract audio from the left part and the extracted audio file should have the same name as the right part so i can later mux them easily with another batch code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%A IN (
 'dir /b /a-d "*.mkv"^|findstr /n /r "." '
 ) DO (
 FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%D IN (
  'dir /b /a-d "%destdir%\*.mkv"^|findstr /n /r "." '
  ) DO IF %%A==%%D echo(mkvextract tracks "%%B" 2:F:\%%~nE.ogg
)

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `destdir` to suit your circumstances.

The required commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, delete the string `ECHO(` which appears before your command to actually execute the commands.

"filter" any line from the directory list containing any character, and number the line with a preceding `#:`. This has the effect of simply producing the same list, but numbered with `#:` preceding.

Tokenise each line into `%%A` and `%%B` using the separating `:` so the number goes to `%%A` and the filename to `%%B`.

With each `%%A,%%B`, do the same trick to the other directory, this time producing `%%D,%%E`, then if the line numbers match, execute your command with the appropriate selection of elements from the variables.

Comment: Thank you! It worked! Unfortunately I am not able to understand most of this.Forgive me if it's silly!  First, what do you mean by **setting** 'sourcedir' ? do you mean 'destdir' (as i don't see any sourcedir in the code) .    Second,  by "**number the line with a preceding #:**" you mean renaming all my files as "1:<name>" "2:<name>" "3:<name>" etc in both source & dest dirs? (I didn't do it but still it worked). And I also didn't understand the last paragraph :(

Comment: Yes - `destdir` (fixed). `dir|findstr /n /r "."` will produce `dir` lines as you are aware, but with a number prefixed like `x1.mkv` will become `3:x1.mkv`. You're already aware of what `/b` does to a `dir`; `/a-d` says "no directorynames". `|` means 'send output from this command to the next'.  The `/n` on the `findstr` says 'number the selected lines'; `/r "."` says 'select lines containing any character'. The caret `^` tells `cmd` that the pipe `|` is part of the command to be executed, not of the `for` controlling the execution.

Comment: The outer loop tokenises `3:x1.mkv` such that `3` is assigned to `%%A` and `x1.mkv` to `%%B`. The inner loop simply acts on the other directory, assigning line number to `%%D` and name to `%%E`. If %%A=%%D then we have the third line of the first directory in `%%B` and the third line of the second in `%%E` - which is the required match. `%%A` will run from 1 to the number of lines in the directory list, and `%%A` will be equal to `%%D` only for the matching line number in the second directory list. Therefore all that needs be done is to select the full filename `%%B` & name-of-`%%E` to process

Comment: Oh thanks! That clears it. It's wonderful how tokens help so much. And how the variables are automatically assigned by tokens.